# How to find words with length >5 using just 1 array?

Tags: c, arrays, input, char, strlen

I want the user to enter text and that the program finds all words which are bigger than 5 letters and prints them out.

```
scanf("%[^\n]s", ar);
l = strlen(ar);
for (n = 0; n < l; n++) {
    while (ar[n] != ' ') {
        if (ar[n] != ' ') {
            ???
        }
        break;
        if (ar[n] == ' ') {
            ???
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]s", ar);` <-- Remove the `s`

Comment: If the loop executes, then `ar[n] != ' '` is always true. And `if (ar[n] == ' ')` never executes because 1) There is a `break;` before it. 2) Even if there wasn't a `break;`, the loop will stop if `a[n]==' '`

Comment: Suggestion: Use `strtok` with space as the delemeter.

Answer (score 1):

A comparatively easy and robust approach to the same will be:

1. Define the input array.
2. Read the entire input using [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) into the array.
3. Start tokenizing the input array using [`strtok()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok)  based on delimiter, prefereably space , in your case.
4. If token is not NULL, check for the [`strlen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen) of that token to be greater/lesser than `5`.
5. Print accordingly.
6. Stop when the token is NULL.

Answer (score 1):

There are a large number of ways to approach this task. You can either use a start and end pointer and walk down each string placing null-terminating characters at each delimiter and read each word as such, or you can call `strtok` and let it parse each line. **Note:** `strtok` will alter/destroy the original string, so you need to make a copy for `strtok`. (if the copy is dynamically allocated, make sure you preserve the start address so it can be later freed).

On handy way of using `strtok` to parse the words is in a `for` loop, it elegantly handles the first call as the initial condition, and all subsequent calls as the increment. While loops are fine, but `for` is hard to beat here.

After parsing the words, it is just a simple matter of getting their length and comparing that to the value entered by the user. Take a look at the following and let me know if you have any questions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {

    char *ar[] = { "The cat jumped over the lazy dog.",
                "The quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog.",
                "The little boy exclaimed to see such a sight,",
                "and the dish ran away with the spoon.", NULL };
    size_t idx = 0;
    size_t lim = 0;

    printf ("\n The strings in the array:\n\n");
    while (ar[idx])
        printf ("    %s\n", ar[idx++]);

    printf ("\n enter minumum length for string match : ");
    scanf ("%zu", &lim);

    idx = 0;
    while (ar[idx])
    {
        char *s = strdup (ar[idx]);
        char *p = s;
        size_t len = 0;

        printf ("\n string: %s\n\n", ar[idx]);

        for (p = strtok (s, " "); p != NULL; p = strtok (NULL, " "))
            if ((len = strlen (p)) >= lim)
                printf ("    %-10s : %zu\n", p, len);

        printf ("\n");

        if (s) free (s);
        s = NULL;

        idx++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/split_string

 The strings in the array:

    The cat jumped over the lazy dog.
    The quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog.
    The little boy exclaimed to see such a sight,
    and the dish ran away with the spoon.

 enter minumum length for string match : 5

 string: The cat jumped over the lazy dog.

    jumped     : 6


 string: The quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog.

    quick      : 5
    brown      : 5
    jumps      : 5


 string: The little boy exclaimed to see such a sight,

    little     : 6
    exclaimed  : 9
    sight,     : 6


 string: and the dish ran away with the spoon.

    spoon.     : 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Not in the pattern as yours, but should work.

```
int l = strlen(ar);

char* wordstart = ar;
int wordlen = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= l; i++)
{
    if (ar[i] == ' ' || ar[i] == '\0') // assume a[l] == '\0'
    {
        if (wordlen > 5)
        {
            printf("(%.*s)\n", wordlen, wordstart); 
        }
        wordlen = 0;
        wordstart = ar + i + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        wordlen += 1;
    }
}
```